# Recognizing module level tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

How can I get test_greet to run in the below; note: test_one(when uncommented) is seen and run by the test runner; to be specific, I want the line `unittest.main()` to correctly pick up the module level test (test_greet).

```
import unittest

#class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
#    def test_one(self):
#        assert 1==2

def test_greet():
    assert 1==3

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Put it in a `TestCase` subclass. Also note that should be `self.assertEqual(1, 3)` - `unittest` doesn't do assert introspection/rewriting like e.g. `pytest` does.

Comment: @RoyM Are you aware that you commented out not only `test_one` but also the class frame which is important?

Comment: And that's really the gist of my question: if pytest can pick up both tests (class based, and module level), then how can `unittest.main()` do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say i have a file called `MyTests.py` as below:

```
import unittest

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_greet(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,3)
```

Then:

1. Open a `CMD` in the folder that `MyTests.py` exists
2. Run `python -m unittest MyTests`

Please note that, all your tests must have the `test_` otherwise, it will not be run.

Comment: ... you could mention that the prefix `test` is important (maybe OP is aware of that maybe not), also a link to https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html could not harm :)

Comment: although `test_` is a popular prefix for test methods, the documentation states: "A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters **`test`**. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests." (emphasizes mine) (see [section right below the code box there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example))

Comment: I should have been more specific that I would like `unittest.main()` to pick up the tests. I've edited my question somewhat.

Comment: @RoyM I think, you are using a wrong practice to write test. i suggest you to watch this video and edit your question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tNS--WetLI
For sure, i will help you after you watch this video

Comment: Appreciate the input @SalmanLashkarara - but I'm trying to solve this particular problem.. not follow best practices. (As to my motivation for doing so: For quick and dirty coding, I spin up an emacs python buffer and write code and test in the same buffer/file.. I can then execute the code with a single keystroke  - and that speed is important to me).